# PHP Reading / Writing to Windows (small business server) Network Share Permissions

Tags: php, permissions, network-share

I'm having a rough time getting this to work. I'm able to mount the shares on the linux box (centos 6.4) using (in fstab)

```
\\192.168.1.2\MyShare /mnt/myshare cifs credentials=/root/sbs2011-mount-secret.txt,uid=apache,gid=apache 0 0
```

Then via the command line I'm able to cd into /mnt/myshare and ls and see all the directories in there.

The problem comes when a PHP file being served by the linux box tries to read or write to the mount point, it always gets a Permissions error. 'apache' is the user/group the server runs on and ls -la shows the mount point being owned by apache:apache.

The username/password set in my credentials file is the Admin account on the Windows box (sbs 2011), and it doesn't seem to change if I use credentials from a user in the Domain Users group.

On the Windows side, I have Full Control turned on for every possible group/user available on the share, and even anonymous but still no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If any extra info is needed just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh! After all this time, the minute I post a question it gets solved :) All is working if I disable selinux. I can take it from here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just today I had the same [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299523/cant-access-files-on-mounted-shared-folder-from-windows).

Try to run *chmod* on your mounted folder to change it's permissions.

```
chmod 777 myshare/*
```

Hope this helps.